Loading data to Azure SQL database from Excel sheet
Is there a straightforward way to load data into Azure SQL database from an Excel sheet. The various methods I studied are pretty tedious and require either a piece of code, connectors or some other sophisticated process, which complicates the task.
I browsed the Microsoft official web page seeking help to find an easy solution, however the options explained there were all very lengthy and cumbersome. I am looking for an easy click-to-do GUI based simple process that would help throw the data from an Excel sheet directly into Azure SQL database, where the table and the matching schema is already defined.

if you want a single "quick and dirty" method, what's wrong with the Import and Export Wizard?

In MS document they described several ways to import data from Excel to Azure SQL Database. But for Some approaches first you need to covet the Excel file to text file (CSV).

Import Flat File Wizard : Here you can import the data trough SSMS tool from text file to azure SQL by following GUI steps from Import Flat File Wizard.

BULK INSERT : With the help of BULK INSERT T-SQL command you can insert the data from text file to Azure Sql database through SSMS.
Bulk copy tool (bcp) : You can use this BCP tool that should run from command prompt to load data from text file to azure SQL.
Azure Data Factory : It is Azure service that helps you to load data from text file to Azure SQL database. it is also GUI based service.

